# Two SPGridView on one page: Sorting issue

Tags: spgridview

I have two spgridviews on a page, in which if I sort the second grid it calls/triggers the sort event for the first grid instead of triggering it's own event. Same thing happens with other events also like RowDataBound, PageIndexChanging.

I Tried using asp.net grid and tested the scenario, this worked as expected. 
I also tried with sharepoint's list view web-part, this test-case passed as well.

but when I added two of my custom coded web-parts on the page one by one i.e., A and B, I noticed that if I add grid A first and then grid B, it always the triggers the events for grid A.  The events for grid which was added second never gets triggered, instead it makes a call to the event for the first gridview's events and throws an error.

Can anyone help on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure these two `SPGridViews` are bound to different event handlers?

Comment: yes, i am sure.

Comment: Can you post markup and code?

Comment: No, not allowed to do so due to some agreements. But both are SharePoint:SPGridView

and both have an OnSorting method. IDs are different.